# iTunes keeps rejecting my App written in Appcelerator

Tags: ios, appcelerator

iTunes is rejecting my app because some icons don't show up. But they do show up when I use the simulator and deploy to mu phone using ad-hoc. I am not sure why this is. Can any one help me with this issue please? Can icons have "-" in them? Is that a no-no? The only reason that I can think of is probably that.

Comment: Does Apple give out reason when they reject an App ? Have you checked this list : https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/ ?

Comment: It says icons missing. But they show up on the simulator. The have included an image which clearly shows icons missing though.

Comment: Well I found out what the issue was. For anyone having this problem: Use CLI + --forcecopy flag to build the ipa.

Comment: great you've resolved it, but if you do an ad-hoc or appstore build it will always use forcecopy :S